# How to set description for Taxonomy View in Drupal 7 using pre-render

Tags: drupal-7

I have a taxonomy view with the term being the argument.

Using hook `views_pre_render` in a custom module, I can look up the term and set the title of the view (and therefore the title of the page) by using:

`$view->build_info['title'] = $thetitle;`

Where `$thetitle` is a field I look up.

It works fine, and sets my title (and my metatags) to the field.

I would very much like to set the view description as well.

But
`$view->build_info['description'] = 'My Description';`

Doesn't work.

So does anyone know of a way to programmatically set a view description?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, that was easy.  Apparently, no need to use build_info, a simple

$view->description='My Desc';

Worked fine.